# Is it possible to switch between pages PageView with ToggleButtons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried to give ToggleButtons pageController, but it doesn't work.

Comment: you can scroll page view on switch toggle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scroll `pageView` on `Switch` toggle like this:

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Center(
        child: ToggleButtons(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                '1',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                '2',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          onPressed: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              if (index == 1) {
                controller.nextPage(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.easeInOut);
              } else {
                controller.previousPage(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.easeInOut);
              }
              for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
                isSelected[i] = i == index;
              }
            });
          },
          isSelected: isSelected,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: PageView(
          controller: controller,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @ReginaldStudyman